# AutoCompleteTextView with CursorAdapter works on virtual device, but not on physical device

Tags: android, android-contacts, autocompletetextview, android-cursoradapter

This AutoCompleteTextView was working fine, until I created a FilterQueryProvider and passed it to my Adapter's setFilterQueryProvider method. Basically what I'm trying to do is alow the user to input either a contact's name or phone number, and have the relevant contacts show up. Here's my relevant code:

```
    //Set up the behavior for the recipient field.
    AutoCompleteTextView destination = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.destination_number);

    //Get the list of contacts, add it to an array adapter.
    /*
    ArrayList<String>[] contactNames = getContactList();
    ArrayList<String> contactNumbers = getContactNumbers(contactNames[1]);
    */

    //Initialize the CursorAdapter.
    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor nameCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE},
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "> 0", null, null);

    CompleteCursorAdapter mAdapter = new CompleteCursorAdapter(NewMessageActivity.this, nameCursor, false);

    nameCursor.close();

    FilterQueryProvider filter = new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            String query = "(instr(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME +
                    ", '" + constraint + "') > 0 OR instr(" +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                    + ", '" + constraint + "') > 0) AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "> 0";

            return cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE},
                    query, null, null);
        }
    };

    mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(filter);
    destination.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    destination.setThreshold(2);
```

CompleteCursorAdapter is just a simple extended version of a CursorAdapter, and so far it's been working fine. I'm assuming that since I only have a few contacts on the virtual devices I'm testing on, and 100 or so on my actual phone, I'm thinking that the query is simply taking too long, and it's getting killed by the system.

However, even if I'm correct in this line of thinking, I'm not sure what I can do to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was strange. It turns out that my phone must be running an older version of SQLite, since it didn't know what to do with instr(). I was able to work around this using LIKE statements.